# How to add hostname alias for specific port into nginx config

Tags: nginx

I have two separate apps on different ports like so

```
# Server A:
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name foobar.com;
  … #lots of server specific settings
}
# Server B:
server {
  listen 8081;
  server_name foobar.com;
  … #lots of server specific settings
}
```

I want to add 'alias' for `foobar.com:8081` on `baz.foobar.com:80`. I think that I might achieve that with a redirect or a duplicate server config section for ServerB. But I'm looking for a more elegant and correct solution.

Comment: Are foobar.com and baz.foobar.com the same machine?

Comment: Yes it's same machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the server specific configuration into a separate file and include it in multiple `server` blocks:

`/etc/nginx/serverB.conf`:

```
root /srv/www/siteB;
...
```

`/etc/nginx.conf` (or files in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`):

```
server {
    listen 8081;
    server_name foobar.com;
    include /etc/nginx/serverB.conf;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name baz.foobar.com;
    include /etc/nginx/serverB.conf;
}
```

Comment: I'd better sick with one and only file per project, is there any posibility to use "include" with server section from same file and not separate file?

Comment: @DmitriyBudnik Nope.